# JavaScript variable won't increment for condition

Tags: javascript

Some one please explain how I can get the score variable to have one added to it each time a question is answered correctly. Each time I run it I get a score of zero when I answer correctly. Thanks.

```
var questions = [
['What is 1+1?', 2],
['What is 2+2?', 4],
['What is 4+4?', 8],
];

var score = 0;

for(var i=0; i<questions.length; i++)
    {
    var response = prompt(questions [i][0]);
    var correctAnswer = questions[i][1];
    if (response === correctAnswer)
    {
      score += 1;

    } 

    }
document.write('Your score is '+score);


function print(message) {
  document.write(message);
}
```

Comment: "correct answers" are Number ... prompt returns a string - the two are never equal ... try `var response = Number(prompt(questions [i][0]));`

Comment: Or `var response = +prompt(questions[i][0]);`. `prompt()` returns its response as a String.

Answer (score 1):

`parseInt` the result in prompt because you want is a number..

```js
var questions = [
['What is 1+1?', 2],
['What is 2+2?', 4],
['What is 4+4?', 8],
];

var score = 0;

for(var i=0; i<questions.length; i++)
    {
    var response = parseInt(prompt(questions[i][0]));
    var correctAnswer = questions[i][1];
    if (response === correctAnswer)
    {
      score++;

    } 

    }
document.write('Your score is '+score);


function print(message) {
  document.write(message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be because the response from the prompt is a string & you are comparing with number. Used uniary operator(+) to convert into number before comparison

```js
var questions = [
  ['What is 1+1?', 2],
  ['What is 2+2?', 4],
  ['What is 4+4?', 8],
];

var score = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
  var response = prompt(questions[i][0]);
  var correctAnswer = questions[i][1];
   //CHanged here
  if (correctAnswer === +response) {
    score += 1;
  }
}
document.write('Your score is ' + score);


function print(message) {
  document.write(message);
}
```

Comment: nice answer.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Prompt returns a string, and your answers in the array are stored as numbers. Either change your answers to strings or use == instead of === to check for equality. Using double equals will allow the Javascript engine to be flexible with types.